# I can't loop this array without getting an error (React)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, maps, jsx

I am learning React and I have just learned to get input values. I tried to write a code to practice. I had an error I can't solve. I tried everything:

- I tried to put the array map in another function
- I tried to use a return (but React isn't pure js so it didn't work)
- I tried to move the map outside the functions but I need to map the Array each time I press the Add button
- I tried to override the persons variables with the array map

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.
P.S. Sorry for my terrible english

here it is:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    age: '',
  };

  persons = []

  getName = (e) => {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  }

  getSurname = (e) => {
    this.setState({surname: e.target.value})
  }

  getAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({age: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const name = this.state.name
    const surname = this.state.surname
    const age = this.state.age
    this.persons.push(name + ' ' + surname + ', ' + age)
    const persons_list = this.persons.map((person) =>
        <li>{person}</li>
    );
  }

  render ()  {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h1 className='title'>React Database</h1>
        <form action="">
          <input type="text" placeholder='Name' className='name' onChange={this.getName} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" className='surname' onChange={this.getSurname} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Age" className='age' onChange={this.getAge} />
          <button className='add_btn' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add</button>
          <button className='delete_btn' onClick={this.persons.pop()}>Delete</button>
        </form>
        <ul>{this.persons_list}</ul>  // the error is here: I can't use a variable inside a function
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move persons_list inside the render function. You have the list as part of the handleSubmit function.

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const name = this.state.name
    const surname = this.state.surname
    const age = this.state.age
    this.persons.push(name + ' ' + surname + ', ' + age)
    const persons_list = this.persons.map((person) =>
        <li>{person}</li>
    );
  }

//try something like this

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    age: "",
    porsons: [],
  };

  persons = [];

  getName = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  getSurname = (e) => {
    this.setState({ surname: e.target.value });
  };

  getAge = (e) => {
    this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = this.state.name;
    const surname = this.state.surname;
    const age = this.state.age;
    this.persons.push(name + " " + surname + ", " + age);
    this.setState({ persons: this.persons });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("App started");
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="title">React Database</h1>
        <form action="">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            className="name"
            onChange={this.getName}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Surname"
            className="surname"
            onChange={this.getSurname}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Age"
            className="age"
            onChange={this.getAge}
          />
          <button className="add_btn" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Add
          </button>
          <button className="delete_btn" onClick={this.persons.pop()}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {(this.state.persons || []).map((person) => (
            <li>{person}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: Yes, you're right but like that the array will map only once. I want the array maps every time I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about scope. The `persons_list` variable you are using in `handleSubmit` is only visible to `handleSubmit`, you should move it outside the function, or instead do the following

```
render ()  {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h1 className='title'>React Database</h1>
        <form action="">
          <input type="text" placeholder='Name' className='name' onChange={this.getName} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" className='surname' onChange={this.getSurname} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Age" className='age' onChange={this.getAge} />
          <button className='add_btn' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add</button>
          <button className='delete_btn' onClick={this.persons.pop()}>Delete</button>
        </form>
        <ul>{this.persons.map((person) => <li>{person}</li>)}</ul>  // the error is here: I can't use a variable inside a function
      </div>
    );
  }
```